# Drivers don't see the final rotation of a constraint. How to get copied rotation instead of (0,0,0)?

Tags: constraints, drivers

**The Premise:**
Say you have a driver on Bone A that makes it's rotation = 50% of the rotation of Bone B.

Bone B has a copy rotation constraint to copy Bone C's rotation.

My expectation would be that Bone A's rotation would be 50% of Bone C's rotation.

**The problem:**
Bone A does not rotate at all because the driving rotation property on Bone B still shows as 0, 0, 0 even though Bone B has visibly copied the rotation of Bone C.

How would I get a driver to see the final rotation of a bone after applying it's constraints?

EDIT: A tangential part of my problem was I was using the "RNA" "Single Property" for the driver, but by switching to "(x) Transform Channel" I can then specify local space and get the result I want.

Comment: Idk if this would help but maybe try using a driver on bone B that copy's bone C's rotation instead of using a constraint. Or make Bone A copy 50% of the rotation of bone C using drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's reproduce the issue: two cubes, one copying the rotation of the other using a constraint. Each cube has a Suzanne copying the rotation of the cube in front of it, using a driver.

[image]

the driver for "sleeping" Suzanne:

[image]

Changing its type to *Scripted Expression*, default variable type to [image] *Transform Channel* and the property type to the rotation axis of your interest:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems I've been using RNA instead of transform channel. Switching and doing what you said solved my problem!